# Parse Json data from Twitter ASP.NET C# - null data unless parsed into type object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

So I have successfully parsed data from numerous API's but I can't seem to get (some of) the twitter one working.

I am pulling from the endpoint "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"

The json data I am having a problem with is the following (see https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities for more info):

```
"entities":{
    "hashtags": [
        {"text":"myHasTag","indices":[24,53]}
    ],
    "symbols":[],
    "user_mentions":[
        {"screen_name":"twitter","name":"Twitter","id":2353,"id_str":"2353","indices":[5,14]},
        {"screen_name":"TwitterDev","name":"TwitterDev","id":943434,"id_str":"943434","indices":[11,32]}
    ],
    "urls":[]
}
```

I'd like to extract the **hastags** and **user_mentions** but they both come up as null when I parse the data in using a *JavaScriptSerializer*.

In my Model I have the following:

```
public partial class TwitterData_Entities
{
    List<TwitterData_HashTag> hashtags { get; set; }
    List<TwitterData_UserMentions> user_mentions { get; set; }
}
public partial class TwitterData_HashTag
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}
public partial class TwitterData_UserMentions
{
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried adding the line below to each object in *TwitterData_Entities* but it made no difference

> [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_mentions")]

the only thing that works and populates is by using:

```
public partial class TwitterData_Entities
{
    List<object> hashtags { get; set; }
    List<object> user_mentions { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to use the "object" type as it wont work for my purposes and it also creates inconsistency in my data structure too.

What do you guys suggest to fix the problem? I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to deserialize it the following way:

```
var json = "{" +
            "  \"entities\": {" +
            "    \"hashtags\": [" +
            "      {" +
            "        \"text\": \"myHasTag\"," +
            "        \"indices\": [ 24, 53 ]" +
            "      }" +
            "    ]," +
            "    \"symbols\": [ ]," +
            "    \"user_mentions\": [" +
            "      {" +
            "        \"screen_name\": \"twitter\"," +
            "        \"name\": \"Twitter\"," +
            "        \"id\": 2353," +
            "        \"id_str\": \"2353\"," +
            "        \"indices\": [ 5, 14 ]" +
            "      }," +
            "      {" +
            "        \"screen_name\": \"TwitterDev\"," +
            "        \"name\": \"TwitterDev\"," +
            "        \"id\": 943434," +
            "        \"id_str\": \"943434\"," +
            "        \"indices\": [ 11, 32 ]" +
            "      }" +
            "    ]," +
            "    \"urls\": [ ]" +
            "  }" +
            "}";

var javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserialized = javascriptSerializer.Deserialize<TwitterData>(json);
```

This is just the JSON you provided nested in { ... } to make it a valid JSON and the actual deserialization.

My classes are the following:

```
public class TwitterData_Entities
{
    public List<TwitterData_HashTag> hashtags { get; set; }
    public List<TwitterData_UserMentions> user_mentions { get; set; }
}
public class TwitterData_HashTag
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}
public class TwitterData_UserMentions
{
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}

public class TwitterData
{
    public TwitterData_Entities entities { get; set; }
}
```

The important thing is to use the `public` access modifier for the properties of the `TwitterData_Entities` class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're a life saver. I will accept this as the answer.